# Safe copying of WordPress pages

Tags: wordpress

Is this a safe way to make a minor change to a WordPress page created with Beaver Builder theme and plugin?

1. Copy page X using *Duplicate This* plugin
2. Change Title and slug of copy (call it Y here)
3. Modify layout in Y, test it's OK
4. Delete X
5. Rename Y's Title and slug to X's original title and slug.

Comment: that won't really work, mostly because your pages are referenced by post_id in the menu, not by slug. with your method, your page gets a new id.  check if revisions are available in Beaver Builder. What you describe is a problem many builder have where the source-code is not available to copy. That's why i work with WP Bakery, you simply copy the well readable code into a textfile (or use revisions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `Beaver Builder Theme` (cool name though), but this seems like a bad idea. You actually create a new page, with a new id, permalink and creation date. This aint helping your search rankings.

A better idea is to copy the original page and edit that copied page and copy the contents to the original page.

1. Duplicate the original page
2. Edit the duplicated page as you like
3. Copy all content from the copy page to the original page
4. Delete the copied page

Depending on the theme options (I have no knowledge of how beaver works) you might be able to copy and paste everything.

Another option would be to copy the post_content field in the database using phpmyadmin.